# string variable with sql query is changed by the framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

This one is weird guys... I have the following method which executes a simple `SQL` statement against a table called `tbl_Users`.  However the compiler or framework or whatever is changing the `SQL Command`.

```
internal bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
   try
   {
      string sqlQuery = "SELECT UserName FROM tbl_Users where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password";

      SqlParameter[] parms = new SqlParameter[] {
         new SqlParameter("@UserName",username),
            new SqlParameter("@Password", password)};

      MembershipUserCollection users = FillUsers(sqlQuery, parms);
      if (users != null && users.Count > 0)
         return true;
      return false;
      }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

As you can see the `SQL` is hard coded with a parameter, now take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You really need to salt and hash your passwords. They should never be stored in clear text.

Comment: @Shyju see the screenshot

Comment: Try wrapping your table name with square brackets like `[tbl_Users]` in your sql query and see what happens then?

Comment: I see what you're talking about now.. not sure what to tell you lol.

Comment: So you're saying that when you step over the line that sets the string variable `sqlQuery` its immediately mysteriously changed without any other code running?

Comment: yes we have a ghost here

Comment: Side note - you don't want to do `   catch (Exception ex) {  throw ex; }`.  All it does is truncate the stack trace, making debugging more difficult.  If you're not going to do anything with the error just let it bubble up (take out the `try/catch`.  Or at worst use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`

Comment: something going wrong in the immediate window or quick watch...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely weird.  Two things may help:

1. As mentioned, bracket the table name in square brackets -- [tbl_Users]
2. Use a string literal -- @"SELECT......"

By the way, I did run your code snippet, it didn't do what is happening to you, go figure.  No clue what the actual root cause may be.